# Automating filling Forms

Tags: webforms

Renting houses can be nasty so I need to automate it. Please, have a look at [here](https://www.hoas.fi/web/hak_inet.nsf/WebHakemus?OpenForm&02.07). If you make a mistake, all of your changes are gone. I tried to insert the values in the url like:

```
https://www.hoas.fi/web/hak_inet.nsf/WebHakemus?OpenForm&02.07?PersonFirstName=Alex?PersonLastName=Smith
```

but it does not work. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your query string is incorrect.  It should be:

https://www.hoas.fi/web/hak_inet.nsf/WebHakemus?OpenForm&02.07&PersonFirstName=Alex&PersonLastName=Smith

Secondly, in order to pre-populate the page with the results of the query string, the developer of the page would have had to added logic to extract the query string values and pre-populate the page with those values.  In this case, it does not appear that they have done that.

You could try saving the page locally as HTML.  Then you could modify the HTML to include your default values.  You would also need to update any relative paths to point to the server as a full URL.  Then you could open the page on your machine and hopefully post to the server.  This assumes that they are not injecting any session or other temporary information in the page that they validate.